# Multiple JavaScript libraries with multiple dependencies

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a web app which uses 2 different JavaScript libraries each with a different Jquery version dependency. How can I specify the Jquery version to use with each library?

Comment: What are the two libraries?

Comment: Phono.js and Signalr

Comment: Have you tried using the latest version with both?

Comment: How you load those libraries? Simply by `script` tag or through some loader like RequireJS or Browserify? You host them by your own or on some third-party server or CDN?

Comment: Using a <script> tag.

Comment: And yes, I am using the latest version of each of the libraries.

Answer (score 2):

See: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

> If for some reason two versions of jQuery are loaded (which is not
>   recommended), calling $.noConflict( true ) from the second version
>   will return the globally scoped jQuery variables to those of the first
>   version.

Comment: If the libraries both expect a globally scoped jquery variable, this isn't going to work.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But if not, the solution is valid.

Comment: Including jQuery twice isn't a solution... it's just wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

My vote's on forking whichever idiot module doesn't allow you to specify your own jQuery, and removing that requirement.  Including jQuery twice is really stupid especially because they're almost guaranteed to be compatible versions.